# Fujitsu port replicator compatibility

Tags: laptop, docking-station

We have some port replicators for older Fujitsu Notebooks from the type [FPCPR231](http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/products/computing/peripheral/accessories/notebook/port-replicators/pmod-139373.html).

Now we would like to buy a FUJITSU Lifebook E548 and wonder if the connector is still the same. Unfortunately, there is no list of compatible devices for the older replicators. There's only a description of compatible series, which i don't trust. Does anyone know more about it?